# How do I use JPA to persist a Map (java.util.Map) object inside an entity and ensure the persistence cascades?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dictionary, playframework

I have recently started playing around with the Play! Framework for Java, version 1.2.3 (the latest). While testing out the framework, I came across a strange problem when trying to persist a `Map` object inside a Hibernate entity called `FooSystem`. The Map object maps a long to a Hibernate entity I have called `Foo`, with the declaration `Map<Long, Foo> fooMap;`

My problem is as follows: The correct tables are created as I have annotated them. However, when the `FooSystem` object `fs` is persisted, the data in `fs.fooMap` is not!

Here is the code I am using for the entities. First is `Foo`:

```
package models.test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Foo extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne
    private FooSystem foosystem;

    public Foo(FooSystem foosystem)
    {
        this.foosystem = foosystem;
    }
}
```

And here is `FooSystem`:

```
package models.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class FooSystem extends Model
{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
        name = "fooMap",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foosystem"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo")
    )
    private Map<Long, Foo> fooMap = new HashMap<Long, Foo>();

    public FooSystem()
    {
        Foo f1 = new Foo(this);
        Foo f2 = new Foo(this);
        fooMap.put(f1.getId(), f1);
        fooMap.put(f2.getId(), f2);
    }

    public Map<Long, Foo> getFooMap()
    {
        return fooMap;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Controller` class I am using to test my set-up:

```
package controllers;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import models.test.FooSystem;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.mvc.Controller;

public class TestController extends Controller
{
    public static void index() {
        EntityManager em = JPA.em();
        FooSystem fs = new FooSystem();
        em.persist(fs);
        render();
    }
}
```

The Play! framework automatically created a transaction for the HTTP request. Although data is inserted into the `foo` and `foosystem` tables, nothing is ever inserted into the `foomap` table, which is the desired result. What can I do about this? What am I missing?

Comment: what version of JPA are you using.JPA2 has '@ElementCollection' which does this http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html

Comment: I am using JPA2 as a matter of fact. I tried your suggestion and it worked after I made a few adjustments to the order in which I saved my entities! I will be posting the complete solution within the next 24 hours! It is very late at night where I live, and I need sleep. Thank you for your help! I've seen the `@ElementCollection` annotation elsewhere on the Internet while searching for my problem, but using `@ElementCollection` didn't work the first time I tried it. I'd written it off until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem using the advice of Java Ka Baby. The issue was actually not in my `Model` classes; the problem lay within the `Controller`. Specifically, I was saving the  entities in the wrong order. Once I realized that using the `@ElementCollection` annotation on the `Map<Long, Foo>` produced the same effects as the join table I was manually specifying, I tried I thought experiment where I re-thought how I was saving my entities.

In the code I posted above, you can see in the `FooSystem` constructor that two `Foo` objects, `f1` and `f2`,  are put into `fooMap` before the `Foo` objects are persisted. I realized that if `f1` is not in the database when it is put into the map, how is JPA able to use its ID as a foreign key in the join table?

If you can see where I'm going with this line of reasoning, you can see that the obvious answer is that JPA is *not* able to accomplish this amazing feat of using a foreign key to reference a nonexistent key. The bizarre thing is that the Play! console did not note any errors at all for the original code I posted, even though it was not correct at all. Either  the framework swallowed every `Exception` thrown during the process, or I've written code that *should* produce an `Exception`.

So to fix the problem, I persisted the `Foo` entities before any operations were performed on them. Only then did I put them into `fooMap`. Finally, once `fooMap` was populated, I persisted the `FooSystem` entity.

Here is the corrected `TestController` class:

```
package controllers;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import models.test.Foo;
import models.test.FooSystem;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.mvc.Controller;

public class TestController extends Controller
{
    public static void index() {
        EntityManager em = JPA.em();
        FooSystem fs = new FooSystem();
        Foo f1 = new Foo(fs);
        Foo f2 = new Foo(fs);
        f1.save();
        f2.save();
        fs.put(f1.getId(), f1);
        fs.put(f2.getId(), f2);
        fs.save();
        render();
    }
}
```

And, since I changed `FooSystem`, here is the final code for that class:

```
package models.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class FooSystem extends Model
{
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Long, Foo> fooMap = new HashMap<Long, Foo>();

    public FooSystem()
    {
    }

    public Map<Long, Foo> getFooMap()
    {
        return fooMap;
    }

    public void put(Long l, Foo f)
    {
        fooMap.put(l, f);
    }
}
```