# Play-framework: Hashtable in a model?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to create a model which is a hashtable with a few accessor methods. The model looks like so...

```
public class MyHash(){
    Hashtable<Integer, CustomObject> hash = new Hashtable<Integer,CustomObject>();
    //few accessor methods here...
}
```

This class is then used inside another model. When the other mode initiates its variable like so...

```
this.hash = new MyHash();
```

the following exception occurs...

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /login

Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Security.java around line 70)
IllegalArgumentException occured : No serializer found for class models.MyHash and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable   SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain:  User["hash"])

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: No serializer found for class models.MyHash and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: User["hash"])
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serializer found for class models.ListOfFilters and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: User["hash"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:1784)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:1750)
at play.modules.mongo.MongoMapper.convertValue(MongoMapper.java:12)
at play.modules.mongo.MongoDB.save(MongoDB.java:239)
at models.User.save(User.java)
at controllers.Security.createNewUser(Security.java:70)
at controllers.Security.authenticate(Security.java:36)
at play.utils.Java.invokeStaticOrParent(Java.java:161)
at play.utils.Java.invokeChildOrStatic(Java.java:183)
at controllers.Secure$Security.invoke(Secure.java:187)
at controllers.Secure$Security.access$0(Secure.java:184)
at controllers.Secure.authenticate(Secure.java:64)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class models.MyHash and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: User["hash"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.serialize(StdSerializerProvider.java:62)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:268)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:160)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:131)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:297)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:224)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1030)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:1777)
... 17 more
```

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a little more background? I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with the MyHash class, and whether it's a Model derived class itself (you say it is a model, but it doesn't extend `Model`)?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, you're correct it doesnt extend model. I want to use it to store a hashtable for the user and it's used as a variable in the class `User` which does extend model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get you halfway there: [How do I use JPA to persist a Map (java.util.Map) object inside an entity and ensure the persistence cascades?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521218/how-do-i-use-jpa-to-persist-a-map-java-util-map-object-inside-an-entity-and-en)

But you will still need to make the MyHash itself serializable, so that the framework knows how to store it into the db: it needs to become an @Entity itself.

Answer (score 0):

try adding @JsonAutoDetect to your MyHash class. Check the [jackson docs](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation) for more info.

Also you need to map your hashmap properly as craigmj suggests.