# hashmap mapped to jpa - playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

This is a sample of my table

```
CREATE TABLE elements (
 elementname,
 displaytext
)
```

How do i use jpa and populate hashmap so that i can pass this down to view from controller

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

render(hm);
```

and in view i want to iterate through and get displaytext based on element name

Not 100% sure if this is an overkill or if an easier way exists. Came across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521218/how-do-i-use-jpa-to-persist-a-map-java-util-map-object-inside-an-entity-and-en)

UPDATE1:
Play frame work 1.2.4

Comment: What don't you create an Element class and map it to the elements table. What's the advantage for you to use a map in your case ? What's your play framework version ?

Comment: Please go through all the examples in the Play framework site.It will sure help you to understand everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you need a Map for this but just a list of elements. If I am wrong explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

---

**1rst Solution**

**Your Model:**

```
@Entity
public class Element extends Model {
   public String name;
   public String text;
}
```

**In your controller:**

```
public static void findElements(){
   List<Element> elements = Element.findAll();
   render(elements);
}
```

**In your view:**

```
<ul>
#{list items:elements, as:element}
   <li>Name: ${element.name}, Text: ${element.text}</li>
#{/list}
</ul>
```

---

**2nd Solution**

Otherwise if you need an actual map you can use the model above and populate the map in your controller:

```
public static void findElements(){
   List<Element> elements = Element.findAll();
   HashMap<String,String> hm= new HashMap<String,String>();
   for(Element el: elements){
      hm.put(el.name, el.text);
   }
   render(hm);
}
```

view:

```
<ul>
#{list items:hm.KeySet(), as:name}
   <li>Name: ${name}, Text: ${elements.get(name)}</li>
#{/list}
</ul>
```

---

**3rd Solution**
Create a container for your map:

```
@Entity
public class ElementContainer extends Model {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name_key", nullable = false)
    public Map<String, String> hm;
}
```

Controller:

```
public static void findElements(){
   ElementContainer ec = ElementContainer.find().first();
   Map<String,String> hm = null;
   if(ec!=null)
      hm = ec.hm;
   render(hm);
}
```