# Inserting data in h2 using YAML, Play, JPA and Hibernate

Tags: playframework-2.1

i'm quite new to using **Play** so please bear with me.

I would like to run **jUnit** tests on a my controllers. I want to insert my data using a `test-data.yml` file before the test runs. I have seen how it is done with Ebean but I was hoping not to add another library to the project just for testing.

My question is : can it be done without `Ebean` and if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

If you see [ZenTasks](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks) sample application for Play Framework, the [Global](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/Global.java) class has this `Yaml.load("initial-data.yml")` on a static class called from onStart(). ZenTask sample uses Ebean, but is this the spot you are looking for?
Users are retrieved on a Map object `all.get("users")` but then you can save the data anyway you want. And [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521218/how-do-i-use-jpa-to-persist-a-map-java-util-map-object-inside-an-entity-and-en) answers better to that i guess if JPA in mind.

Another way than YAML is to write Evolutions manually. Ebean generates evolutions for you automatically but you can also write them manually. See:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Evolutions

Comment: Thank you for this answer and sorry about the late reply. I'm going to look into using a Global class in my test directory. That way the initial data will be for tests only.

Comment: There is also Play.isDev() / Play.isProd() / Play.isTest(), see [Play API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/index.html)

Comment: That could be useful, thanks. I prefer not polluting my code with "if test". If I find an alternative I will post it here.